# Отскакивание ползунка QSlider от края

Tags: qt, macos

Как запретить отскакивание ползунка QSlider от края?

upd: Если скроллить мышью, то всё работает нормально, без отскоков. Использовал Qt 5.11.3 Попробовал 5.12.5 ситуация стала лучше, но до конца не исправилось